# Portfolio page on skeleton theme scrolling slow and or jerking in Chrome

Tags: css, performance, scroll, responsive-design

If someone can, please view this page:

http://thebc.co/our-work

Everything is loading fast but when you scroll in Chrome, it isn't smooth at all.

This only happens on the page above. I do not think the images are a problem.  They are super optimized and again, all of the pages load very fast.

The website is built on the skeleton responsive framework.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Also, my 17 rep would not let me add another question and it is 3am and I need to sleep:)

Comment: Another issue with the same page:Please view this in FireFox:

http://thebc.co/our-work

Hover over the images.  The lag time is ridiculous.  This does not happen in Chrome, IE or any other browser.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what was making it sticky when scrolling. It was applied to an image hover.

`border: 1px solid #C02E2C;`